# How to implicitly set UITextView contentSize? (Swift 3/xCode8)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a need to set the contentSize of a non-scrolling UITextView exactly to it's superview's frame. I need to do this for the purpose of getting the range of characters that fit, and while I know there's better methods for doing this, or even better views to be using, I need to use this custom UITextView for it's  [specific capabilities](https://github.com/lingochamp/FuriganaTextView). Simply doing:

```
 textView?.contentSize = superView.frame.size
```

doesn't seem to set anything, and it's contentSize is still as long as it's content. I want to simply truncate the content at where it just wont fit anymore. I'm on Swift 3 and xCode 8 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using `.bounds`:

```
textView?.bounds = superView.bounds
```

That should set all the properties you want to be the same as the super view.

Comment: I tried it, and while it does make the width match, if you feed it a long string it scrolls for about a mile. Check the height in a breakpoint and it's about 4000. Even setting the height of the textview's textcontainer seems to do nothing. This is a tricky one.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Scrolling was enabled. Disabling scrolling seems to have fixed it.